# Why tablayout and actionbar put space in fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Explanation:
            I implemented a navigationDrawer in Activity.There are lot off fragment are available.I used a materialDesign them for my application.
When i put tablayout in activity it's not putting space. When i put tablayout inside one of my fragment it put the space between my toolbar and tablayout.

Here is my fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_schedule"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"

            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_text"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#E15E5E"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my fragment.java

```
public class ScheduleSpinner extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_spinner, container, false);

        tabLayout=(TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_schedule);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Completed"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Upcoming"));
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
                (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.Score).setVisible(false);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ScheduleCompleted tab1 = new ScheduleCompleted();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    ScheduleUpcoming tab2 = new ScheduleUpcoming();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is my v21/Style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In short i used a materialDesign patter in my application.

Below image is implemented inside an activity
[image]

Below image is implemented inside into fragment.

[image]

In Above image i got the problem.I want like my activity in fragment.

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Please, answer me.

Comment: I did not understand the problem. Which space?

Comment: See second image and first image.

Comment: actionbar having shadow in second image

Comment: a space between actionbar and tablayout.

Comment: Do you understood?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the above part is coming from the activity, and the below ones from fragment; therefore, if you want that appear to be flat color, without the gradient, then you should remove

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

from the appbar background at both the activity and the fragment layout, although you did not post the activity layout, I guess it has a similar line in it. If the result won't change, then you should change the theme you used; if you cannot, then simply write something like

```
android:background="@color/color_you_want"
```